# Combining database for multiple clients - good idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, multiple-databases

I've joined a small company which essentially sell one web application. The data in the web app is very sensitive, to the point where all of the data is field level encrypted. App is written in ASP.NET Web API 2(C#), with a html/javascript front and SQL-Server back.

At the moment, they have around 50 clients, and the architecture of the app is that each client gets their own database. They are all deployed into their own IIS virtual directory, which then points to its own DB. The code is exactly the same among all clients.

The owner has told me that this was all by design for security. However, it is an absolute pain to manage, and they are only ever getting more clients.

I've suggested combining it all into one DB, and adding a field on the main table which identifies which client the data belongs to. From here I can filter/join on that field.

The owner does not like this as it introduces a risk: if there is shoddy code, one client may be able to see another clients data. This obviously can't happen with multiple databases, as the connection string won't cross to a different DB.

Is there any possible way to de-risk this? I suggested overriding the authorize class to stop unauthorized users accessing info, but this doesn't solve the whole 'bad code' problem.

Is there anything I can do, or am I stuck maintaining a whole heap of databases?

Answer (score 3):

There is risk in the current setup as well.  What if someone mixes up the database connection strings on the sites?  You will have to determine which is more risky.

If you decide to keep the separate databases it sounds like you need to invest in automation to help manage them.  We use a Database project to source control the database schema/scripts and MSDeploy to automated the deployments to all the databases.  Maybe this would elevate some of your pain with the multiple databases.

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/

Comment: Separate databases also facilitate isolation with database-as-a-service in the cloud.  Automation is the key in that world too.

Comment: The connection string is derived from the Virtual Directory, as the DB Name (Initial Catalog) is the same as what's used in the VDir. We've tried to automate as much as possible (deployment using web deploy, updates, etc) but it's still painful when things go wrong, and we only have 50 clients at the moment, can't imagine it at 500 or 5000 :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that here is a right or wrong answer here, it's really up to the risk appetite of the given company (or its owner).

It seems lot less likely that a connection string points to the wrong database, than writing a code that accidentally (or intentionally) pulls other company's data from a single database.

The separate database architecture offers one huge advantage over the shared database one besides security: this is restoration of data. In the event you need to restore only a single client's data, the separate database design allows you to do this in such way that it does not affect other customers. In case of a shared database, any restoration procedures would affect the service of other clients as well.

There can be a middle ground between separate databases and shared database: separate schema. If you use this approach, the separate schemas still maintain a degree of separation, but you have a lot less database instances to manage, so the service can scale better.

There is a good article on MSDN that takes a look at all 3 options: [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). The artice describes the advantages and disadvantages of all 3 scenarios.

However, pls bear in mind that all this is really up to the subjective risk appetite of your company!

Comment: Fantastic article. Really helped. You're 100% right regarding data restoration, much easier to do when dealing in individual DB backup files versus encrypted tables. One of the problems I forgot to mention above is that we currently have users on a per client basis, which doesn't work if a user has access to different instances of the app (as they will have multiple logins), but I think this can be solved by moving users to a shared DB and overriding the authorize class. P.S. thanks for the edit fixing the tag above.